# "TypeError: cannot instantiate ctype 'EVP_MD_CTX' of unknown size" while trying to build google prediction api

Tags: python, google-api, google-prediction

Below is the code

```
import httplib2, argparse, os, sys, json
from oauth2client import tools, file, client
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from googleapiclient import discovery
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only']

def get_api(api, scope, service_account=True):
     storage = file.Storage('oAuth2.json')
     creds = storage.get()

     if creds is None or creds.invalid:
        creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('service_account.json',
                                                             scopes=scope)
        storage.put(creds)

     http = creds.authorize(httplib2.Http())
     return discovery.build(api, 'v1.6', http=http)

api = get_prediction_api('prediction')
```

Below is the error

> TypeError: cannot instantiate ctype 'EVP_MD_CTX' of unknown size

Based on this [blog](http://cloudacademy.com/blog/google-prediction-api/)

Using this [google-api-python-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client)

Answer (score 3):

I found this post [oauth2client](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/issues/641) relating the problem, in my case the problem was solved updating to latest version of pyOpenSSL, 16.2.0 at the time of writing.

Comment: Should've asked earlier, but which python version did you use? and did you use conda venv or python venv?

Answer (score 1):

The google-api-python-client that I installed (link above) only works with python2. As of today, it doesn't work with python2 inside of conda env, only outside of conda env, and doesn't work with python 3.5.

Comment: do you have a reference for that? The [github page](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client) says it's fully compatible with Python 3.4 and `This library may work on later versions of 3, but we do not currently run tests against those versions.` I'm just surprised that it would work on 3.4 and not 3.5

Comment: Hmm I have a similar experience, this error does go away when I try python 2.7

Comment: Actually I have this working now in Anaconda Python 3.5.2. Unfortunately I don't have the exact steps but I believe it was `pip install pyopenssl` and making sure `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` was set

Comment: I didn't have any reference as in blogs/articles, but I tried it out on my own. My thought exactly like yours after I read the github page. I didn't upgrade pyopenssl, so maybe that's why it didn't work for python 3.5 inside conda for me. Did you install or upgrade pyopenssl and is it inside of conda env ? I have pyopenssl 16.0.0, and it looks like I need to upgrade it to 16.2.0 according to @Chemary above

Comment: no that is a difference, I'm using python [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) but I was getting the same error

Answer (score -1):

I don't have the points to upvote but Chemary's answer worked for me. I am using python 3.5. I faced the same issue and it got resolved when I installed pyOpenSSL.

```
pip install --upgrade pyOpenSSL
```